# Splash Screen da error y cierra la aplicacion

Tags: java, android

Buenas estoy definiendo un Splash Activity en mi aplicacion lo cual resulto mas fácil de lo que esperaba, lo definí de la siguiente manera:

Class:

```
    public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {


  private static final long SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(
                    SplashScreenActivity.this, howto.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);



            finish();
        }
    };


    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY);
  }

    }
```

Manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Bien hasta ahi todo perfecto, la aplicacion ejecuta, y luego del splash abre un activity sencillo con instrucciones de la aplicacion, el problema esta al querer que el activity sea el Main mucho mas completo, se muestra el splash pero acto seguido la aplicacion se cierra, porque puede suceder esto? Probé de muchísimas maneras incluso sacando partes del codigo, re-estructurando, y no logro que se ejecute el Activity solo si lo dejo limpio con el layout me lo muestra pero cuando declaro algo por mas mínimo que sea deja de funcionar devuelta

**Logcat**

> 11-23 13:54:17.754 28358-28583/es.hol.galu.uris E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load DynamiteLoader: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/es.hol.galu.uris-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/es.hol.galu.uris-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>   11-23 13:54:18.727 28358-28358/es.hol.galu.uris E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                     Process: es.hol.galu.uris, PID: 28358
>                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.hol.galu.uris/es.hol.galu.uris.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>                                                                         at es.hol.galu.uris.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
>                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
>                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Manifest de la actividad que quiero abrir luego del splash:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
                   android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

OnCreate:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Sección con comparación equals():

```
      Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
    String receivedAction = receivedIntent.getAction();
    String receivedType = receivedIntent.getType();
    //make sure it's an action and type we can handle
    if(receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)){
        //content is being shared
    }
    else if (receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)){
        //app has been launched directly, not from share list
    }

    String receivedText =                        receivedIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    //check we have a string
    if (receivedText != null) {
        //set the text
        et1.setText(receivedText);

    }
```

Comment: Que error te muestra

Comment: Se cierra la aplicacion luego del splash

Comment: Me refiero a que error te muestra en el _LogCat_

Comment: @FrancoGaluzzi es importante agregar el mensaje de error del LogCat.

Comment: Ahi lo agregue, edite la pregunta y agregue al final el error de LogCat

Comment: Muestranos el error. Podrías intentar hacer que tu Activity main fuera la que estás intentando llamar desde el Splash, y que al cargar te muestre el Splahs como un activity o una ventana de pantalla completa durante un periodo de tiempo y tras ese periodo se cierre.

Comment: Creo que el problema viene por como esta estructurado el Activity quizá por el Action Bar?

Comment: @FrancoGaluzzi agregué una respuesta, aunque probablemente tienes más detalles.

Comment: No es recomendable forzar un tiempo de espera obligado, el Splash Screen debe mostrarse sólo y únicamente durante el tiempo que la app necesite y no obligándola a "detenerse" durante cierto tiempo, he ahí la diferencia entre un buen y un mal Splash Screen. Un buen ejemplo de Splash Screen (en Inglés): https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu intent es incorrecto, debe ser:

```
  Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
  startActivity(mainIntent);
```

Después de eso existe un error dentro de la clase MainActivity.java :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object

La variable `receivedAction` tiene valor null por esa razón marca error al cargar MainActivity.

```
 String receivedAction = receivedIntent.getAction();
    String receivedType = receivedIntent.getType();
    //make sure it's an action and type we can handle
    if(receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)){
        //content is being shared
    }
    else if (receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)){
        //app has been launched directly, not from share list
    }
```

Por la forma que se realiza tu Intent este valor será null ,ya que no estas enviando un tipo de acción especifico, **debes enviar el tipo de acción,** por ejemplo:

```
  Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
  mainIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  startActivity(mainIntent);
```

Comment: El intent funciona correctamente si la clase es "howto" si la clase es el activitymain deja de funcionar, con tu ejemplo o con el que tenia anteriormente

Comment: agrega como tienes configurada MainActivity en tu AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Muestra tu _ActivityMain_ entonces

Comment: @FrancoGaluzzi espera, muestra tu clase MainActivity ya que en realidad es la del problema:  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference at es.hol.galu.uris.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44) at

Comment: Es lo que trataba de decirle a @x4mp73r pero la clase es muy extensa para publicarla completa, alguna parte de la clase en especial puede ser de ayuda? Ahi agregue el manifest que me pediste

Comment: Ok si es así  puedes agregar la sección donde tienes una comparación equals()

Comment: Agregue la sección con la comparación equals()

Comment: @FrancoGaluzzi gracias, he agregado la actualización.

Comment: El intent que dices recibe MIME desde otra aplicacion, por eso da null, de que manera lo puedo corregir? definitivamente al correr la aplicacion sin el intent funciona correctamente

Comment: Excelente @Elenasys Lo solucione agregando "mainIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);" al intent del splash

Comment: Podrias explicarme porque soluciono el problema?

Comment: Así es, para recibir una "acción" mediante .getAction(), necesitas agrear un tipo de acción al generar el Intent, de otra forma si no defines una acción, receivedIntent.getAction(); tiene un valor null por no contener un tipo de "acción" especificado , saludos! =)

Answer (score 1):

Revisa estas opciones:

Que tengas a tu *Main* dentro del archivo *Manifest* justo después de tu actividad de *splash*

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Veo que la llamas ***howto*** a la actividad que se inicia después de ***SplashActivity***, entonces sería:

```
 android:name=".howto"
```

Por lo tanto quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
                android:name=".howto"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: howto es la actividad que nombre como "sencilla" solo con unas pestañas y las instrucciones de la aplicacion, el manifest de la activity main es identico al de "howto"

Comment: No es problema del manifest

Comment: Entonces explícate mas por favor, a lo que entiendo a tu pregunta es que no inicia la actividad después del _Splash_, si dices que no va por ahí, especifica bien y explica de forma clara para que entandamos tu situación.

Comment: No hay que explicar, si luego del splash llamo a un activity en blanco o sencilla funciona con normalidad, si llamo a un activity mas complejo la aplicacion deja de funcionar, el error esta ahí pero no logro encontrarlo

Comment: "Bien hasta ahi todo perfecto, la aplicacion ejecuta, y luego del splash abre un activity sencillo con instrucciones de la aplicacion, el problema esta al querer que el activity sea el Main mucho mas completo, se muestra el splash pero acto seguido la aplicacion se cierra"

Comment: ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar TODO tu _Manifest_? También sería bueno ver tu clase Main.

Comment: Eso no se entiende, modifica tu pregunta con mi comentario.

Comment: El manifest es el mismo que publicaste vos, solo que tiene 6 activitys mas, y no es posible agregar todo la clase Main dado a que es demasiado extensa

Answer (score 1):

Si ya tienes registrada la segunda actividad en el `manifest.xml`, prueba mandando a llamarlo con lo siguiente:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, howto.class);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Es la forma clásica de llamar una nueva actividad.
El problema puede ser debido a que, la segunda actividad que tienes se encuentra en otro paquete de tu programa.

Comment: El intent funciona correctamente si la clase es "howto" si la clase es el activitymain deja de funcionar, con tu ejemplo o con el que tenia anteriormente

Comment: Ya veo, el problema esta cerca del método `onCreate` en la línea de código 44 como le indica el LogCat

java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference at es.hol.galu.uris.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)

Comment: Puedes publicar el `onCreate` del MainActivity?

Comment: Ahi lo agregue @rockar06

Answer (score 1):

Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

SplashActivity.java

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Tiempo de duracion del splash
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000; //variable

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { //tiempo mostrara la pantalla del splash
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent displayOrder = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class); //el orden el que se abriran los xml
            SplashActivity.this.startActivity(displayOrder); //inicia la actividad

            SplashActivity.this.finish(); //fin de la actividad
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT); //duracion del Splash

} //./OnCreate
```

} //./SplashActivity

activity_splash.xml

```
android:id="@+id/content_splash"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">
```